# How to count re-borrowers that had a lower interest rate than the existing old ones?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a table of loan records that contains, among other things, the annual interest rate (`annual_interest_rate`), an monotone increasing sequential ID (`loan_id`) and the ID of the borrower (`member_id`).

I'm trying to count the re-borrowers (i.e. members with multiple loans) that had a new loan with a lower interest rate than their previous loan.

A sample of data is given below:

```
Annual_interest_rate | Loan_id | Member_id
 0.2850              |  1      | -9832
 0.1482              |  2      |  6982
 0.065               |  3      | -9832
 0.1754              |  4      |  1234
 0.2387              |  5      |  1234
```

In this sample data, the only re-borrower with a lower interest rate on their later loan than on their earlier one is member -9832, so the total number of such re-borrowers should be one.

How can I count the total number of such re-borrowers?

Comment: Martijn Pieters I wanted to attach a photo of my table yet it does not allow me unless I have 10 points ... Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Ilmari Karonen I re-edited the table. So the individual with id -9832 appears twice in the member_id column but in the Annual_interest_rate he gets different interest rates as the -9832. Is this better explanation? Hopefully! I am new to SQL and even coding in general so I am not even able to verbalise what is correct :) Apologies

Comment: I am looking for the total number of those who re-borrowed at the lower interest rate. Sorry again for not being clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of different ways to solve this using SQL.  All of these are pretty standard SQL queries, and should work on any more or less ANSI SQL compatible database, not just SQLite.

Perhaps the conceptually simplest way would to use a [subquery](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/exists.php) to look for loan records where there exists another, later loans record with the same member ID and a lower interest rate:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Member_id
FROM Loans AS OldLoan
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Loans AS NewLoan
    WHERE NewLoan.Member_id = OldLoan.Member_id
      AND NewLoan.Loan_id > OldLoan.Loan_id
      AND NewLoan.Annual_interest_rate < OldLoan.Annual_interest_rate
)
```

This query will return the IDs of all the members who have at least one pair of loans with the later one (by loan ID) has a lower interest rate than the earlier one.  If you just want the *number* of such members, replace `DISTINCT Member_id` with `COUNT(DISTINCT Member_id)`.

The `EXISTS` condition in the query above evaluates to true if the inner `SELECT` matches at least one row.  Note that it doesn't matter what columns the inner query is supposed to return, since `EXISTS` cares only about whether there result has any rows or not, so I've simply told it to return a single column containing the constant `1` for each matching row.  (The database engine probably optimizes even this constant away, in any case.)

You can think of this query as simply looping over each row of the table, and then using an inner loop over the *same* table again to see if there's another row with the same `Member_id`, higher `Loan_id` and lower `Annual_interest_rate`.  That may of may not be how SQLite engine actually ends up implementing the query, but the results you'll get will be the same in any case.

---

Alternatively, instead of a subquery, you could use a [self-join](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-self-join/) of the `Loans` table with itself.  There's a couple of equivalent ways to write that.  For example, you could simply list the table twice (with different aliases, of course) in the `FROM` clause, and then use the `WHERE` clause to match up the rows, like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT OldLoan.Member_id
FROM Loans AS OldLoan, Loans AS NewLoan
WHERE NewLoan.Member_id = OldLoan.Member_id
  AND NewLoan.Loan_id > OldLoan.Loan_id
  AND NewLoan.Annual_interest_rate < OldLoan.Annual_interest_rate
```

(Note that here we need to explicitly specify the result column as `OldLoan.Member_id`, since both the `OldLoan` and `NewLoan` tables — or, rather, aliases to the same table — are now used in the outer query, and they both have a `Member_id` column.  Of course, the `WHERE` clause ensures that the member IDs will be the same for all matching rows anyway, but the SQLite parser isn't clever enough to realize that.)

For simple queries like this, this style of writing joins works fine.  For more complex queries where you join many tables together, however, using explicit `JOIN` ... `ON` clauses can be tidier, e.g. like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT OldLoan.Member_id
FROM Loans AS OldLoan
JOIN Loans AS NewLoan ON NewLoan.Member_id = OldLoan.Member_id
WHERE NewLoan.Loan_id > OldLoan.Loan_id
  AND NewLoan.Annual_interest_rate < OldLoan.Annual_interest_rate
```

And since you're joining the two tables (or rather, in this case, the same table under two different names) by matching columns with the same name, you could even use the equivalent shorthand syntax with `USING()`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT OldLoan.Member_id
FROM Loans AS OldLoan
JOIN Loans AS NewLoan USING(Member_id)
WHERE NewLoan.Loan_id > OldLoan.Loan_id
  AND NewLoan.Annual_interest_rate < OldLoan.Annual_interest_rate
```

All of the queries above are equivalent, in the sense that they will return the same results, and the last three (using self-joins) should also give the exact same execution plan, and thus run equally fast.  The subquery version *might* use a different execution plan, depending on the database engine you're using.  On SQLite it seems that it does, but some other databases might optimize both the subquery and the self-join to execute the same way under the hood.

In any case, to make any of these queries run efficiently on a large table, you should *at least* have an index on the `Member_id` column, so that the database engine can easily find pairs of loans belonging to the same member without having to scan every pair of rows in the table.  Depending on the database you're using, the size of your table and the typical number of loans per member, some other indexes *could* also be useful, but that's getting into the esoteric realm of database performance fine-tuning.  In any case, as long as no single member has an absurdly large number of loans, just the simple index on `Member_id` should be fine.

Ps. [Here's an SQLFiddle demonstrating all these queries.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/b90e1/2)  You can use it to check that they work, and that they all return the same results.  If you want, you can also click "View Execution Plan" to get more information about how SQLite actually runs these queries.

Comment: Ilmari Karonen - you just the best!!! Can you please advice of a thorough Cheat Sheet on SQLite functions? Have in mind that I am very very beginner on this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gabriel: [This one](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-cheat-sheet/) was the first result I got when I googled for "sqlite cheat sheet", and it doesn't look half bad. You might also want to consider looking for a basic SQL tutorial, either online or as a paper book from the library. SQL as a language is pretty old, and for basic stuff like this even a ten or twenty year old book should be fine. It doesn't have to be specifically about SQLite.